# Eclipse: installing find bug not allowing,

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Problem with installing find bug eclipse, 
"Unable to connect to repository http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/site.xml   Connection refused: connect "

Can any body help me why connection is refusing .

Comment: Are you using the correct url? http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse Can you connect to other update sites? Proxy?

Comment: Its coming org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisonal.p2.core.Provision Exception

Comment: Hi Alexandar aand RAS I am using eclipse-3.5 version , I am using correct url findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse . but it is not connecting , while I am testing connection , by using Test Connection button , It is giving "Unable to connect to repository findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/site.xml Connection refused: connect "

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some network settings are missing from your Eclipse.  You must set your proxies explicitly in the Eclipse preferences.  You can do so here: Preferences -> General -> Network Connections.